# chrome extension - Pass message among background, content script, and popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message

My content script code includes:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log(message);
    console.log(sender);
});

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener((port) => {
    if (port.name === 'knock') {
        console.log(port);
        port.onMessage.addListener((msg) => {
            console.log(msg);
        });
    }
});

var port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: 'knock' });
```

While in background

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener((port) => {
    if (port.name === 'knock') {
        console.log(port);
        port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        });
    }
});

var port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: 'knock' });
```

And popup

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: 'knock' });
port.postMessage({ message: { success: true } });
```

The background environment receives and logs message successfully, while none of content script logs run. I'm confused by this. How could I send message through a port (establishing a long-lived connection) from background, popup to content script environment and vice-versa?

Comment: You don't connect *to* the content script - [chrome.tabs.connect](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-connect) does that. You don't send messages to the content script as well -
 chrome.tabs.sendMessage does that. BTW usually such complicated communication scheme is not needed.

Comment: You're confusing two different methods of communication here. In an extension, you can send messages either using a port or using one-off messages. `chrome.runtime.connect` and `chrome.runtime.onConnect` are for setting up port communication. `chrome.runtime.onMessage` is for listening for messages that were sent using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` or `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`. Also, the behavior of these APIs is different in background vs. content scripts vs. popup. Check out the Chrome API documentation for in-depth explanations of this: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging